# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "quesadilla"?

Tags: etimología, méxico, comida

Según la definición de la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UoUSna0), la ***quesadilla*** es:

> 3. f. *Méx.* Tortilla de maíz rellena de queso **u** otros ingredientes que se come caliente.

Más completa en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quesadilla_(M%C3%A9xico)#Diferencias_entre_la_Ciudad_de_M.C3.A9xico_y_el_resto_del_pa.C3.ADs), pero la esencia es la misma:

> La quesadilla es un platillo mexicano que consiste en una tortilla de maíz, o también de trigo, doblada por la mitad que puede estar rellena de queso **o** de otros ingredientes y que se come caliente.

Al denotar la conjunción disyuntiva *o* y *u* deduzco que una quesadilla puede o no llevar queso, lo cual desencadena una batalla interminable entre los habitantes de la Ciudad de México (y sus alrededores) y los estados de provincia, los cuales aseguran que la quesadilla debe llevar queso.

Por ejemplo:

- Si una persona de la Ciudad de México pide una quesadilla de pollo, se refiere a una tortilla doblada que contiene únicamente pollo.
- Si una persona de alguna provincia pide una quesadilla de pollo, se refiere a una tortilla doblada que contiene queso y pollo.

Investigando acerca del origen de la palabra, no hay fuentes confiables. Por ejemplo:

- El vocablo náhuatl **quetzaditzin** que es totalmente falso, en esa lengua no existía la letra *D*, además, el término que hace referencia a una tortilla es [Tlaxcalli](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortilla_de_ma%C3%ADz). La terminación *TZIN* hace alusión reverencial.
- La página [WowRestaurant](https://deliciasprehispanicas.com/tag/quetzaditzin/) asegura que el término quesadilla proviene 100% de España, eso debido a la terminación *illa*.
- La página [La hoja de arena](http://www.lahojadearena.com/de-quesadillas-sin-queso-y-gente-hipercorrecta/) dice que el nombre hace honor al relleno, así como la forma de la tortilla doblada forma una letra *D*.

Hay un sin fin de fuentes, sin saber si realmente son veraces.

El meollo de este asunto es para conocer su origen, y con esto determinar si una quesadilla en su momento debía o no llevar queso.

Comment: Eso me recuerda al "pastel de arroz", un dulce típico de Bilbao que curiosamente no lleva arroz más que en el nombre. Algunas teorías dicen que en su origen se hacia con harina de arroz pero actualmente no, aun así conserva el nombre. Algo similar sucedería con las quesadillas que mantienen el nombre original aunque haya variedades sin queso.

Comment: @blonfu por alguna razón no había visto tu comentario, el cual me recuerda a un lugar en las cercanías de la Ciudad de México denominado el *Desierto de los Leones*, que ni es desierto y que tampoco hay leones, jaja.

Comment: Desierto también es un lugar despoblado, así que _Desierto de los Leones_ podría ser un sitio despoblado de leones, tiene sentido xD.

Comment: @blonfu ahora que lo mencionas, tiene sentido jajaja. La persona que pensó ponerle ese nombre realmente sabía lo que hacía :P

Comment: Para las personas oriundas de Oaxaca no hay lugar a dudas pues usamos el término empanada para referirnos a todo lo que no contenga queso y que sea preparado con queso o quesillo envuelto en una tortilla de harina.

Comment: Esto ocurre también en otros idiomas. Así, la mayoría de los *plum cake* ingleses no llevan ciruelas, y los *Leberkäse* alemanes tampoco suelen llevar hígado ni queso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buscando el término *quesadilla* en diccionarios históricos, veo que ya en el siglo XVII existía la palabra. Una de las primeras definiciones del término aparece en un diccionario español-francés de 1607, en el que se dice que una quesadilla es "une tartelette de fromage" (que, si mi francés no me engaña, significa "queso"). En un diccionario español-inglés de 1617 se define como sinónimo de "quesada": "a cheesecake".

Ya en 1737 la RAE lo define como

> cierto género de pastél compuesto de queso y massa, que se hace regularmente por carnestolendas

Quitando lo de "carnestolendas" (es decir, "carnaval"), el resto de la definición sigue tal cual en el DLE hoy día.

Sin embargo, si lo buscamos en el CORDE vemos que hay casos incluso hasta en el siglo XV:

> Artocrea es empanada de carne como artotira es empanada de queso que dezimos quesadilla.
>
> Alfonso de Palencia, "Universal vocabulario en latín y en romance", 1490 (España).

Nótese que este caso es incluso anterior al descubrimiento/invasión (elíjase el que proceda) de América por parte de Cristóbal Colón. Y si buscamos "quesada" (palabra de la cual parece provenir), se encuentran casos anteriores:

> Ay, allende d'esto, otras cosas de cortar compuestas, ansí como queso e huevos fritos o en tortilla, quesadas e tartaras e tortas e ojaldes e juncadas e otras d'esta condiçión que non es neçesario alongar el dezir en sus cortaduras, nin fazer d'ellas capítulo aparte.
>
> Enrique de Villena, "Arte cisoria", 1423 (España).

Por tanto, originariamente y en su acepción española (de España), la palabra *quesadilla* sí que implicaba el queso. Esto, claro está, es si queremos remitirnos al origen del término. Otra cosa es el origen del plato mexicano. No sé si la actual quesadilla mexicana fue una evolución paulatina de la quesadilla española, o si fue una invención repentina a la que dieron el nombre de "quesadilla" en honor a la quesadilla española, o si se le dio el nombre de "quesadilla" sin tener nada que ver con la quesadilla española y es simplemente una coincidencia. En cualquiera de los tres casos, veo difícil que se le diera ese nombre sin que, al menos de forma inicial, llevara queso. Otra cosa es que al final haya prevalecido el nombre de "quesadilla" para designar a todos los platos que tienen la misma forma, ya con independencia del relleno.

Answer (score 3):

Quesadilla *viene* de queso, pero no tiene que contenerlo (si lo contiene, o cúanto, o si es un taco, no es la pregunta).

Pese a esta etimología, *quesadillas*  en provincia llevan queso y en CDMX, no. Pedir que sólo uno de los grupos tenga razón es ignorar cómo el significado de las palabras está en función del lugar donde se pronuncian (haz el experimento para *coger* o *paro* en español latinoamericano, comparándolo con el peninsular:

¿Algún uso es incorrecto? ¿Alguien tiene que tener razón?). Ambas son correctas. Un capitalino en provincia tiene que pedir una quesadilla "sin queso" si no lo quiere dentro de la tortilla. Un provinciano en la capital tiene que pedirla "con queso" (cuando se le pregunte y la pregunta no tiene que ofender, pese a la etimología, su lógica).

Comment: La palabra tiene toda la pinta de venir de *queso*, pero no hay algo que realmente lo demuestre. Estoy de acuerdo que en el contexto actual ambas puedan ser correctas, simplemente lo que busco es el origen, para saber cuál es variación de cual, no digo que los de la capital estén bien o que los de provincia estén mal, solo es saber en dónde nació todo este embrollo.

Answer (score 1):

Una quesadilla sin queso no es más que un taco, por modo de que un taco es oficialmente un platillo servido envuelto en una tortilla. Un taco se define en la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YvQrYuw) como tal:

> *10. m. Tortilla de maíz enrollada con algún alimento dentro, típica de México.*

Viendose esto con precisión de láser, la definición de un taco en la RAE dice que debe ser de maíz. Creo es errónea porque una tortilla de harina podría por igual usarse para servir un taco. Por lo tanto, no prestaría tanta atención a lo que define una quesadilla como *de queso u otros ingredientes* como veridico al 100%.

Yo prefiero dar por definida la palabra según su incepción como denotando un alimento creado con queso, tal su nombre de **quesa**dilla.

También vale observar que por el mismo, *de queso u otros ingredientes* da la posibilidad de que esta sea rellena de únicamente queso, como por igual de queso más otros ingredientes, y no exclusivamente de queso más otros ingredientes. De ser a cambio *de queso **y** otros ingredientes*, se excluye que sea únicamente de queso, que no tiene ningún sentido en lo absoluto.

**EDIT:** He llegado a una fuente sumamente veridica con información relevante al tema. Favor de leer lo que se encuentra aquí: [Minucias del lenguaje, escrito por José G. Moreno de Alba, publicación en la Academia Mexicana de la Lengua.](https://www.fondodeculturaeconomica.com/obra/suma/r3/buscar.asp?idVocabulum=56&starts=Q&word=quesadilla)

En esta publicacion se da a conocer que la palabra quesadilla deriva de la palabra quesada, un "pastelillo compuesto de queso y masa", o "un dulce a modo de pastelillo relleno de almíbar, conserva o algun otro manjar", más el diminutivo -illa.

Etimologicamente se comprueba el vínculo con el hecho que lleva queso, pero la publicación reconoce el "desplazamiento semantico" del significado de la palabra en CDMX, y que tal como se usa, deja de ser algo que debe llevar queso a algo que lo puede llevar por opción. Tal para cual, es correcta de ambas formas, pero originalmente, o más bien dicho, anteriormente, la quesadilla mexicana llevaba queso.

Comment: Es algo diferente, una tortilla enrollada estoy de acuerdo que es un taco, y la definición de Wikipedia dice claramente, una tortilla *doblada*, más no enrollada.

Comment: @Flxtr ¿Acaso no conoces los tacos doblados? Por ejemplo, de atún con lechuga. Por lo general, doblados y dorados. No dejan de ser tacos. Por igual, tu le pides unos tacos al taquero en la esquina, no te los entrega enrollados sino doblados.

Comment: Me parece que eso es tema de otra conversación. Ahora, sin desviarse del tema, creo que principalmente busco el origen de la palabra *quesadilla*, sin importar que pueda ser tratada como taco. Considero que la pregunta es clara y directa, no es necesario darle vueltas y meterse en otros líos.

Comment: @Flxtr estoy de acuerdo. Mi punto en particular es que no estoy seguro de que se puede confiar en la definición de la RAE al pié de la letra, tal como es, porque existen infinitésimas variaciones para un taco, y una quesadilla es una de ellas. Es un taco especial, de cierta forma. Pero, a mí me resuena el hecho de que lleva queso en el nombre entonces debe llevar queso en el alimento. De no ser así, debería de llamarse un taco.

Comment: El taco no se fríe.  La quesadilla sí. Por otra parte, ni en el taco ni en la quesadilla se enrolla la tortilla.  Definitivamente, se dobla. // Para el origen -- no sé, pero creo que además de los ingredientes lingüísticos, *queso* y *tortilla*, también podría ser *empanada*. // Creo yo que la quesadilla tiene que llevar queso, y otros ingredientes de relleno son optativos.

Comment: @aparente001 la quesadilla no tiene que freírse, puede freírse.

Comment: @aparente001 El taco puede freírse. No lo es necesario, claro, pero es posible dorar un taco (con aceite, que lo hace frito), y es esta versión de un taco que conlleva erroneamente a la versión estadounidense de un taco, hecho con una tostada doblada

Comment: @walen La ensalada tiene etimología diferente a la palabra sal. Ensalada deriva del latín vulgar salata, que es forma corta de herba salata, que NO es hierba saladas, sino hierbas dulces. Que una ensalada lleve o no sal es irrelevante porque la procedencia de la palabra es otra. Aparte, la RAE no reconoce la palabra tosta. Se dice por ahí que es corrupción de tostada, y se usa para toda manera de sandwiches de cara abierta.

Comment: @walen De ningún modo te he concedido la razón. Solamente tendrías la razón si al igual fuera hecho que la parte *quesa-* en quesadilla fuera más o menos una coincidencia (como lo es con sal y ensalada) y en realidad no fuera relacionado con queso. De momento eso es indeterminado. Podrá ser que la ensalada no lleva sal, pero sí lleva *salata*. Tu argumento es inválido.

Comment: @psosuna en todas partes donde busco *salata* significa salado.

Comment: Para mí, si se fríe, no es un taco, es una *frita* (si lleva frijoles, con queso o sin queso), o es una quesadilla (no lleva frijoles).  Si la quesadilla no se fríe, no es quesadilla. // El *taquito* es otra cosa... *taquito* = *snack*.

Comment: @aparente001 Muy interesante. ¿Se puede preguntar de que región eres? De donde és mi familia, desconocemos la *frita* (es decir, por sí sola). Les decimos a cada uno de estos dos un *taco dorado* o una *quesadilla frita*, y la nomenclatura cambia dependiendo de que si lleva queso o no. Un *taquito* es un "snack", como decir *echarse un taquito* para decir comer algo ligero, o algo pesado en porción reducida. Al igual, un taco enrollado frito lo conocemos como una *flauta*.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con la flauta.  Aprendí a cocinar en el estado de Veracruz.  Pero he visto que los términos de cocina son quizás lo que más varía según la región.  Ahora te pregunto, si untas frijol machucado o refrito en una tortilla, y la pones a freír, quizás pones quesito encima, ¿cómo se llama?  (Se dobla después de sacar del sartén.)  Esto es para mí *la frita*.

Comment: Creo le llamaríamos un taco a eso, debido a que no hicieramos algo así. Si el taco llega a freirse es para que salga crujiente y dorado. De tal forma, ya está doblado antes de dorarse. Pero, la noción de una tortilla con frijoles y queso no es nada extraño para mí (creo es dentro de las comidas elementales en todo México), aun así le llamaríamos un taco, como dije anteriormente. A propósito, mi familia proviene de Durango y de la Baja California Sur.

Answer (score 0):

Ya aprendimos por las respuestas anteriores que "**quesadilla**" es el nombre de un alimento en Mexico.
Ahora lo complicado, resulta que en Colombia usamos la palabra "**quesadillo**" para referirse a un alimento hecho con queso suave (no madurado), al cual se le da forma de empanada, cuyo interior está relleno de "bocadillo".
Este "bocadillo" es un alimento, más precisamente un dulce que se hace de una fruta que en Colombia denominamos "guayaba".

También tenemos el "**quesariquipe**", que es también hecho de queso suave (no madurado) pero está relleno de "arequipe", que es un dulce que se hace a partir de leche y azucar morena.